# How are the Polish, Czech and Slovenian PMs going to travel to Kyiv without getting harmed?

Tags: armed-conflict, ukraine, poland, czech-republic, slovenia

[Czech, Polish, Slovenian PMs visiting Kyiv to meet Zelenskiy](https://www.rferl.org/a/ukraine-kyiv-czech-poland-slovenia-visit/31753678.html)

How do the Czech/Polish/Slovenian PMs know their transport isn't going to be attacked? They are after all going through a war zone.

Only thing I can see is that they are going to liaise with the Russians first, but given that they're going to Ukraine to offer support, it seems unusual that Russia will agree.

Comment: The visit is over and they seem to not have got harmed. Maybe the assumption that Russia would like to try to attack them was wrong.

Comment: Because if they tried to, NATO and Russia would get into direct conflict.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For a start, they're taking a train - Michał Dworczyk, the Head of the Polish Prime Minister's Office, held a [press conference](https://www.gov.pl/web/premier/briefing-prasowy-szefa-kancelarii-prezesa-rady-ministrow) on the morning of the 15th in which he informed reporters that the train carrying the PMs had just crossed the Polish-Ukrainian border. This information was also released [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/PremierRP/status/1503649173861720069) by the Chancellery of the Prime Minister. According to the [BBC's Katya Adler](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-60757157), this decision was taken "because flying by Polish military jet could have been viewed by Russia as dangerously provocative".

The news organisation PAP [reported](https://www.pap.pl/aktualnosci/news,1115544,jaroslaw-kaczynski-mateusz-morawiecki-udaja-sie-do-kijowa-spotkaja-sie-z) on the press conference held by Dworczyk, which included a question on how the leaders' security would be ensured (my translation):

> Dworczyk was asked how the security of politicians going to Kiev would be ensured. "Today, hundreds, thousands of civilians in Ukraine, children, women, not to mention soldiers, are dying under Russian fire, but it is known that civilians are most affected in any war. And today everything must be done to stop the Russian aggressor. This is a risk that must be taken. In such situations, danger is inevitable " - said Dworczyk.
>
> At the same time, he stressed that "of course, you always weigh the related risks." "Here, after an analysis not only at the Polish level, because, as you can see, this delegation is international, it was decided that such a trip must be carried out. We cannot allow the Russians to continue these criminal activities in Ukraine," he stressed.

The Mayor of Kyiv, Vitali Klitschko, [announced](https://kyiv.klichko.org/klychko-z-20-00-15-bereznia-do-7-00-17-bereznia-v-kyievi-zaprovadzhuietsia-komendantska-hodyna/) that Ukraine's military command has imposed a curfew in the city from 8pm on the 15th until 7am on the 17th, although it's not clear that this is specifically related to this visit.

Finally, Petr Fiala's [announcement of the visit](https://twitter.com/P_Fiala/status/1503633295682289664) on Twitter notes that international organisations including the UN have been informed of the visit - Dworczyk mentioned that the international organisations informed also included NATO and OSCE. Russia is a member of OSCE and, of course, the UN and we can probably conclude that forces around Kyiv will have been made aware of the visit, as an attack, accidental or otherwise, on three NATO heads of government on a well-publicised visit would probably be seen as escalatory.

Comment: [Also reported by Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/three-eu-country-leaders-take-train-kyiv-show-support-ukraine-2022-03-15/), you beat me by one minute. Worth mentioning that Poland did something similar during Russia's invasion of Georgia in 2008.

Comment: Hmm, this makes me wonder why Russia doesn't seek to take control of the train line to Kyiv, which after all is fixed and unchanging. I would imagine the rail line is relatively easy to attack as well, since it is presumably hundreds of kilometers long, and a breach at any point will stop the train.

Comment: @Allure Why would they? The line goes through West Ukraine, which has no Russian presence. The best thing for Russia is to have nothing to do with the meeting.

Comment: @Allure If Russia wants a full scale NATO intervention into the war in Ukraine, then attacking that train might be good way to get it. I just don't think Russia wants that right now, it rather seems their wish is that the west just ignores whatever is happening in Ukraine.

Comment: @quarague they don't have to attack the train, they can attack the railroad. Also I am not convinced NATO will intervene if it happens - the attack would be outside NATO soil. The PMs presumably know that too, hence they're referring to risk in CDJB's answer.

Comment: There is also a curfew closing down the city of Kyiv during the visit (https://twitter.com/KyivIndependent/status/1503663694730903561).

Comment: The curfew is highly unlikely to be connected to the visit. This is just part of preparations for the expected Russian assault on the city.

Comment: @quarague : the strong "need" that they have to travel there personally and cannot organize a meeting in any other way blew all my suspension of disbelief. This looks more like some NATO countries desperately *wanting* these MPs to be attacked, and definitely not the other way around.

Comment: +10 " ...  an attack, accidental or otherwise, on three NATO heads of government on a well-publicised visit would probably be seen as escalatory ..." :-)

Comment: @vsz These are national leaders. They surely don't personally want to be killed by Russians, and who could force them to go against their will? This is a gesture of defiance. Doing it over the internet wouldn't have the same effect.

Comment: @vsz Speaking from Poland here. Our ruling party for years emphasized courage, sacrifice, war heroes, cult of people who risked their life to fight Soviet Union, and so on. They built younger part of their electorate based on this. They cannot avoid going there in person now. And if they believe what they preach, they don't want to. They don't want to be killed, but they do not fear that. Or, at least, need to look like they don't.

Comment: @quarague Russia's nuclear potential has backed NATO into a corner militarily, I seriously doubt anything but a full scale invasion of a NATO country would get a response. Killing NATO citizens who entered a known war-zone (or "special military operation zone") wouldn't be enough for them to trigger a war.

Comment: I assume the reason that taking a train helps is that by traveling on a set route at a set time, it makes an "accidental" attack impossible. If Russia attacks their train, then it's pretty clearly a deliberate attack and military escalation which would necessitate a response from those 3 countries, if not NATO at large. Is that the idea @CDJB?

Comment: @divibisan yes, combined with the fact that flying a NATO aircraft into a contested airspace seems fairly inadvisable. I wrote my answer while the question still referred to the original article title which referenced the PMs flying out, I'll edit to make this more explicit.

Comment: I think the 3 of them going in the same train is also a big deal.

Answer (score 13):

> How do the Czech/Polish/Slovenian PMs know their transport isn't going to be attacked? They are after all going through a war zone.

They don't!

They're mainly relying on the assumption that civilian transport should not be targeted by the Russian military, because that would constitute a war crime (unless the Russians had reason to believe the train was also carrying military personnel or equipment).  Whilst we do have evidence of some cases of civilians being targeted, we have more evidence of civilians being allowed to pass.  The Russians aren't simply shooting anything that moves.

So whilst it's certainly risky, they're taking the same risk as reporters, medics, and other non-combatants.

Comment: With the same logic however they could have targeted them when they met Zelenskyy because he is a military target. The Russian army also didn't or couldn't do that.

Comment: @Trilarion The Russians have been trying hard to target Zelenskyy for almost three weeks, with no success. So *couldn’t* is right.

Comment: The Russians -- or at least their leadership -- don't seem to have any qualms about attacking civilian targets, war crimes or no.  Their attacks may not be altogether indiscriminate, but the three PMs would be foolish to rely on their transport being civilian in nature to protect them.  And they are not foolish.  It is not accidental that they announced their visit and publicized it widely.  They want to be sure that if Russian forces do target them then it cannot be construed as accidental, and they are relying on Russia not wanting to be seen to attack them intentionally.